# Sublist values to two different variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, subprocess

I'm trying to assign two values of a list to two different variables. Here is the json list. Its raising `key error`. Please let me know where I am wrong.

```
[{'min': 1.158, 'max': 1.150, 'id': 269097, 'to': 1532003820, 'from': 1532003760, 'check': 1.15852, 'no_check': 1.15822, 'volume': 0},{'min': 1.1, 'max': 1.17, 'id': 269098, 'to': 1532003880, 'from': 1532003820, 'check': 1.158615, 'nocheck': 1.158515, 'volume': 0}]
```

Here is my code python3 code:

```
pt = [{'min': 1.158, 'max': 1.150, 'id': 269097, 'to': 1532003820, 'from': 1532003760, 'check': 1.15852, 'no_check': 1.15822, 'volume': 0},{'min': 1.1, 'max': 1.17, 'id': 269098, 'to': 1532003880, 'from': 1532003820, 'check': 1.158615, 'nocheck': 1.158515, 'volume': 0}]

y = [item[0] for item in pt]
z = [item[0] for item in pt]
print(y)
print(z)
```

Error:

```
File "test_YourM.py", line 19, in <module>
  y = [item[0][0] for item in pt]   File "test_YourM.py", line 19, in <listcomp>
  y = [item[0][0] for item in pt] KeyError: 0
```

Expected output:

```
print(y) # {'min': 1.158, 'max': 1.150, 'id': 269097, 'to': 1532003820, 'from': 1532003760, 'check': 1.15852, 'no_check': 1.15822, 'volume': 0}
print(z) # {'min': 1.1, 'max': 1.17, 'id': 269098, 'to': 1532003880, 'from': 1532003820, 'check': 1.158615, 'nocheck': 1.158515, 'volume': 0}
```

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries. You need to access it using a `key`

Comment: `item[0]` doesn't exist, you could try `item['min']` etc.

Comment: 1) The code in the error message is different from the code in your question; please decide which code you want to use and what error it produces; 2) what _is_ `item[0]`? What do you expect it to be?

Comment: Following your edit, what's wrong with `y, z = pt`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Assign each element of a List to a separate Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300174/python-assign-each-element-of-a-list-to-a-separate-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[item for item in pt[0]]
[item for item in pt[1]]
```

The item is generated in in that scope, while pt isn't, even though you're enumerating a dict, you may want to do something like this:

```
{key: value for key, value  in pt[0].items()}
{key: value for key, value  in pt[1].items()}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code? Does it produce the output the OP wants?

Comment: `{key: value for key, value  in pt[0].items()}` is identical to just `pt[0]`, likewise for `pt[1]`, why would you do this?

Comment: There's no promise that iterating `pt` will give both key and value at all python versions, where as `items()` does do that.

Comment: `pt` doesn't have keys, it's a list, iterating it will give the objects, which is what's wanted

Comment: I ment `pt[0]`.

Comment: That's fine, I meant there's no point using `{key: value for key, value  in pt[0].items()}`. As `pt[0]` on its own does the exact same thing, no matter what version of python you're using