# how to assign each element of array to different variable in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, variables

The array size is vary depending on the user input

for example with size of 3

```
array = [1,3,7]
```

to get

```
a = 1
b = 3
c = 7
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign each element of a list to a separate variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300174/how-to-assign-each-element-of-a-list-to-a-separate-variable)

Comment: Preferably use [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) though

Comment: don't waste time for this. Keep it as array and use `array[0]`, `array[1]` or even `array[other_variable_with_number]`. And `array` will be more useful when you have to iterate it - `for item in array: ...` or check how many elements you have `len(array)`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enumerate to get both the number and the index at the same time.

```
array = [1,3,7]
for pos, num in enumerate(array):
    print(pos,num)
```

This will give you a output like this:

```
0 1
1 3
2 7
```

So now to access the number at `index 0`, simply write,

```
for pos, num in enumerate(array):
    if pos == 0:
        print(num)
```

Which will give you this output:

```
1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

if you have name of the variables than you can use this

`(a,b,c) = array`

You probably want a dict instead of separate variables. For example

```
variavle_dictionary = {}
for i in range(len(array)):
    variavle_dictionary["key%s" %i] = array[i]

print(variavle_dictionary)

{'key0': 1, 'key1': 2, 'key2': 3,}
```

Comment: sorry bro that needs a lot of clarification, but actually I tested that was wrong so sorry!

Comment: idea is good but I would use `for i, item in enumerate(array):` instead of `range(len(array))`