# Beautiful Soup more than 1 result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```py
try:
    src = soup.find("div", {"id": "image-block"})
except AttributeError:
    continue
```

It works great, but the problem is:
when I get one url it's ok, but when I receive five urls they come inside the same variable.

I need to specify 10 variables:

- img1
- img2
- img3
- ...

If BS finds only 1 url it puts it into url 1,
but if BS finds 3 urls, it separates them and puts them into different variables.

Thanks you for your help

EDIT

Thanks you so much for your help but sometime i have 1 image to get and sometime 8.

So i get this :

var1, var2, var3, var4, var5,var6, var7, var8 = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "image-block"})

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 8, got 1)

But if i put : var1 = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "image-block"}) it's works but put all in var1

My problem is that i don't know how much image i have to get on each loop.

Thank you again for you time.

Comment: why not use a list? instead of hardcoding it for different variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to specify 10 variables img1 img2 img3:

You can use `find_all()`. Since `find_all()` returns a  `ResultSet` (a list), you can unpack the variables as follows:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 = soup.find_all('img')
```

this will create 5 different variables: `var1`, `var2`, etc.

Make sure the length of the variables you are unpacking is the same length that `.find_all()` returns.

##### See also

[How to assign each element of a list to a separate variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300174/how-to-assign-each-element-of-a-list-to-a-separate-variable)

Comment: What do you think about this way 
longueur =  len(total)
                    
                    
                    
                    if (longueur)==1:
                        var1= soup.find_all("div", {"id": "image-block"})
                        print(longueur)

                    if (longueur)==2:
                        var1,var2= soup.find_all("div", {"id": "image-block"})
                        print(longueur)